# How to make editable only one point on google maps polygon?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

is there a way to edit on;y one point?
So if I enable "editable:true" on triangle polygon then I can move only one point, but the other two is not movable/editable. Maybe hide the editable circle somehow? 
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't even think those are angles are markers.

I think you just have to add an editable marker on top of the non clicable polygon.

If it doesn't show or isn't clicable try playing with the z-index of the marker